# How to display a numbered list in batch program?

Tags: command-line, batch

I want to display a text file in my command prompt using batch file such that, if the content of my text file is as follows

> Hi there!
>
> My name is Pranay.
>
> I want to try giving numbers to the lines in my text file.

The output in my command prompt (but not in my text file) should be as follows:

> 1) Hi there!
>
> 2) My name is Pranay
>
> 3) I want to try giving numbers to the lines in my text file.

Pls do help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is not a difficult problem, but we expect users to make some effort to solve things themselves before asking us to give up our free (and unpaid) time to write customised scripts.

Comment: In my college, for my course in UNIX programming I have learnt that we can achieve it in UNIX by command named  "nl"  hence I tried that command in my windows command prompt using " nl hello.txt ". But the prompt said no nl command found.

Comment: You could start with `findstr /N "^" yourfile`, see http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: So? Didn't your college teach you the difference between Unix and Windows?

Comment: Hence I searched for the problem over google, yet I have not found any favourable answers. So I asked it here

Comment: @JosefZ Nice try, but it doesn't number the line like `1) `, `2) ` etc :)

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %G in ('findstr /N "^" file.ext) do @echo %G^) %H` if @DavidPostill  expects full answer… I gave only a starting point…

Comment: @DavidPostill My college just gave the difference between the working of each UNIX and WIndows OS , their architecture, but not any in depth command line arguments or functioning of command prompt.

Comment: @JosefZ I wasn't expecting a complete answer. I know several different ways to do this. I was hoping the OP would make some kind of effort before we spoon fed him. Nice solution though! ;) Unfortunately the OP has probably learned nothing other than how to get people to do his work for him :/

Comment: @PranayRaju please follow David's advice; http://ss64.com/ is definitely a good site for learning `cmd` commands and `.bat` scripting with `cmd` × `bash` cross references

Comment: @JosefZ yeah sure

Comment: The `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN (file)` is a good starting point to then do a `CALL` passing the `%A` to another routine with `SET /A` to add 1 to the variable & echo accordingly from there with `>>` to another file... A good starting point indeed.. I wrote something here apparently that does something similar http://superuser.com/questions/990804/writing-to-file-with-find-command-in-a-batch-script/991735#991735 perhaps. Another good starting point. Update your answer with what you try and we can give an an answer if you still have trouble. this is indeed simple See **EXPLICITLY DEFINED SCRIPT**